# Create post request to specific method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have a controller called "AgendaComplejoController". In this controller I have my index view. Ito my index.blade.php I have a form with a button(I made a form just to make a post request):

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/guardarTurno') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success button-infousuario">
   <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></span>
       Confirmar turno
   </button>
</form>
```

I want to call a function into my Agendacontroller

```
public function guardarTurno(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('entré al guardar turnos');   
    Log::info('json: '.json_encode($request));  
    }
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('/guardarTurno', 'AgendaComplejoController@guardarTurno');
```

I have the following error:

> > MethodNotAllowedHttpException

But I can't connect my blade view with my controller method.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to `POST` to a `get` route. Change your route from get to post.

Answer (score 1):

In your router, you're registering the route as a get.

```
Route::get('/guardarTurno', 'AgendaComplejoController@guardarTurno');
```

And your form, your submitting as a post.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/guardarTurno') }}">
```

So change your method to a post:

```
Route::post('/guardarTurno', 'AgendaComplejoController@guardarTurno');
```

Comment: My index receive an object. I want to send in the post the same object and id. How can I change the request to make that I want? I forgot writing in the topic